# How to route nginx pages to different pages?

Tags: nginx

Hello I have django app  let's suppose my site uri is example.com now i want to route my admin dashboard to another port like if users types `abc.example.com` it automatically routes to main page of my app but i want to have `abc.example.com:445/admin/*` is it possible the solution i tried was

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name abc.example.com;
  client_max_body_size 500M;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/my.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
  }
} 
server{
  listen 445 ssl;
  server_name abc.example.com;
  client_max_body_size 500M;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/my.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;

  location /admin {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name abc.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

But this itself routes to port 443 and /admin page is also available there so how to avoid this any possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a location block in the second server block (listening on port 445) to handle requests to /admin. It will proxy requests to http://localhost:3001. However, I also included a location block to return a 404 error for any other paths (e.g., /) on this port to prevent access to these paths over port 445.

By doing this, only requests to abc.example.com:445/admin will be routed to your application, while other paths will return a 404 error. The main site on abc.example.com (port 443) is not affected by these changes.

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name abc.example.com;
client_max_body_size 500M;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/my.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;

location / {
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
 }
}

server {
     listen 445 SSL;
     server_name abc.example.com;
     client_max_body_size 500M;

     ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/my.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;

  location /admin {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
   }
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
  server {
   listen 80;
   server_name abc.example.com;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all listen on port 80 and redirects all requests to `https://abc.example.com:445` because it ensures that all requests for `abc.example.com` are redirected to your desired port and then listen on port 445 and handle requests for both the main page (`/`) and the admin page (`/admin`),so the `location /` block proxies all requests to `http://localhost:3001`, which is where your Django app is running!

check this out :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name abc.example.com;

  location / {
    return 301 https://$host:445$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 445 ssl;
  server_name abc.example.com;
  client_max_body_size 500M;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/my.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
  }
}
```